# How to retrieve file in hdfs that were permanently deleted

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I accidently deleted a file in hdfs that contains information about hive (e.g. metadata etc.) At that time trash was not enabled also. How can I retrieve tose file

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without having Trash enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The only way to retrieve the a deleted file in hadoop is to recover it from trash.